How to set the Contentful Data model to have only one single instance?
How to have only one single instance (or existence) of a Contentful Headless CMS Data Model?
Right now I can all multiple entries of each Contentful Model. For some items like AboutSectionText, I would like the user to not create duplicate entries of a single model.
Below is my screenshot of the Contentful Data model:

